# Tutorial first steps Microsoft Go

Tags: go

I am starting to learn Go following this [Microsoft tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-mx/learn/modules/go-variables-functions-packages/4-packages).  The program runs and displays the result as in the tutorial, but the two problems that it is marking me cause me concern. I do not want to continue without understanding what this detail is due to, someone who has also happened to it, or who helps me to know what it is due to, I will be very grateful.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/x0z38/calculator"   
    "rsc.io/quote"
)
func main(){
    total := calculator.Sum(3, 5)
    fmt.Println(total)
    fmt.Println("Version: ", calculator.Version)
    fmt.Println(quote.Hello())
    
}
```

I leave you the image where the error is marked in red lines in the editor:

[image]

I leave the image of the two problems:

[image]

According to what I understood is that it does not find those files in any of the mentioned paths, but both files if I have them inside this path: C:\Projects\Go\src.
My GOPATH environment variable is: C:\Projects\Go

Comment: Run `go mod tidy` in your project root and it should download the required modules for you. You may need to authenticate against Github as the dependency `github.com/x0z38/calculator` is a private repo.

Comment: GOPATH is no longer used, make sure you have your module setup correctly, and don't use `GOPATH/src` for the module code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have learned is that you want VS Code (or gopls) to correctly identify a multi-module project. Please refer to [this](https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/master/gopls/doc/workspace.md) (your are using Go1.18).

And more about [go modules](https://go.dev/blog/using-go-modules).

And [go workspace](https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/workspaces).

Hope those can help you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Golang has two ways to manage dependencies: old and new. Switching between them is usually done automatically.

Visual Sudio Code tries to check for dependencies using the old way. But I see you have `go.mod` and `go.sum` files which means you are using the new way (the Golang module system).

The environment variable `GO111MODULE` is used to switch between dependency control modes. It has 3 values: `auto`, `on`, `off`. The default is `auto`.

What you see is just a syntax highlighting problem and not a compilation or execution error.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is what I did:

First: Run go mod tidy as suggested by Mushroomator in my root project, and it didn't work

Second: remove the GOPATH environment variable, since as JimB commented it is no longer used, and it didn't work either.

Now, this is where I feel a bit confused, because maybe I did what they asked me to do but I don't know how to explain it.

So, it works and no longer shows a syntax error. Delete the GOPATH environment variable, SET GOMODULE111=on, and take out the Projects/Go directory where I have all the files and put it on the desktop and mark this syntax error:

[image]

Google
Todo
Imágenes
Noticias
Shopping
Vídeos
Más
Herramientas

Cerca de 1,260,000,000 resultados (0.39 segundos)
Español
Inglés

Now, as you can see, I open VS Code directly in the helloworld directory, and the syntax error disappears, but I wanted to have it open directly from the src directory to see everything I've learned so far:

[image]